# Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow. When Delete Data in AS400

Tags: c#, db2, ibm-midrange

I've got a strange error when I tried to delete data from AS400. When I executed this program, on state cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() I got Arithmetic Operation Resulted in an Overflow.

I don't use any numeric here, but I got an error like that.
I've tried to debug this program but there is no problem when executing cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() statement. But when I run the executable file the error always show up. I don't understand what mistake that I made. Hope anybody can help me. Thanks...

This is the source code:

```
...                
using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand())
{
   cmd.Connection = conn;
   cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM MDPDTAM.IWMDPOC";
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
...
```

I've tried to execute query manually from AS400 and it's work fine.

Comment: Do you have any "on delete" triggers?

Comment: No, I don't have any triggers.. I've tried to execute the query manually in as400 and it's work fine.

Comment: Probably not the actual solution. You could compare the config file in source code with the one in executable folder -> probably using different settings such as Naming format/keyword. Try .Net provider or Oledb, i face less problem with these two compared to Odbc

Comment: How many rows are being deleted?  Is it possible that the number of rows 'updated' is overflowing a counter in the driver?  It'd potentially only be possible if they used an `int`, though...

Comment: I've tried to delete only one record and no record in the file. But it has same error. :(

Answer (score 3):

Do you have the actual SQL error code?  You can use the [SQL message finder](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzas2/rzas2finder.htm) for more detailed information.

I would recommend starting with [Collecting an ODBC Trace (SQL.LOG)](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzaii/rzaiiodbc58.htm) to identify any issue.

If that doesn't help I would examine the **QZDASOINIT job log** using the steps outlined in [Server-side ODBC diagnostic and performance tools](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzaii/rzaiiodbc62serverside.htm).

Answer (score 3):

Coming to this question late, but I will leave this in case others come across this question. I also had an arithmetic overflow on a call to an AS400 program that returned no data and was using `ExecuteNonQuery`.

The key was the stack trace:

```
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcStatementHandle.RowCount(SQLLEN& rowCount)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetRowCount()
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.FirstResult()
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader, Object[] methodArguments, SQL_API odbcApiMethod)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Even though no rows were being returned from the call an exception was thrown processing the return code.

I found that the project has switched to creating a 64-bit application instead of 32-bit (even the vshost executable was 64-bit). The ODBC driver being used was 32-bit, so the mismatch caused an exception. Changing the project to x86 solved the problem.